# Uri.TryCreate does not produce the result I expected

Tags: c#, uri

I'm scraping a website for URL's and the anchor tags all have their href value just set to the querystring eg..

```
<a href="?AppId=12345&CatId=13">Details</a>
```

The URL of the current page is something like this..

```
http://www.theurl.com/ThePage.aspx?PageNo=2
```

Therefore the url I'm looking for will be

```
http://www.theurl.com/ThePage.aspx?AppId=12345&CatId=13
```

To get this I am using the the method Uri.TryCreate, so I'm passing in the following parameters (the first two parameters are of type Uri and not string)..

```
Uri.TryCreate("http://www.theurl.com/ThePage.aspx?PageNo=2", "?AppId=12345&CatId=13", out uri);
```

However the out parameter 'uri' is being set to..

```
http://www.theurl.com/?AppId=12345&CatId=13
```

As you can see it removes the .aspx path.  Can you recommend a better way to do this or explain why it doesn't work as I thought it should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Uri.TryCreate("http://www.theurl.com/ThePage.aspx?PageNo=2", "ThePage.aspx?AppId=12345&CatId=13", out uri);
```

According to [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131573.aspx), the first one is the base URI, the second is the relative URI.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. I'm not sure the behaviour that happens is correct. That may well be a bug.

In any case, you might find the following handier:

```
UriBuilder uBuild = new UriBuilder("http://www.theurl.com/path/thePage.aspx?PageNo=2");
uBuild.Query = "AppId=12345&CatId=13";
Uri newUri = ub.Uri;//http://www.theurl.com/path/thePage.aspx?AppId=12345&CatId=13
//Note that we can reuse uBuild as we continue to parse the page, as long as we're only dealing with cases where only the query changes.
uBuild.Query = "AppId=678&CatId=2";
Uri anotherUri = ub.Uri;//http://www.theurl.com/path/thePage.aspx?AppId=678&CatId=2
```